# Using Active Directory replication over unreliable WAN

Tags: active-directory, ldap, wan

I want to use Active Directory replication between two sites that have unreliable, perhaps even only periodic (daily) WAN connectivity. I have no experience managing Active Directory or LDAP services prior to this effort.  Access control and other role changes are infrequent (say weekly) in my organization, and instant replication is not necessary.

Is this even possible? Are there alternative modes of Active Directory that I should explore to solve this?

Comment: Is the time window predictable (eg. "connectivity is usually OK between noon and 3pm")?

Comment: Yes, predictable in the sense that the connection will be up *sometime* between noon and 3pm. @MathiasR.Jessen